# Confusing error while reading a .txt file in r

Tags: r

I have a .txt file that contains 44 columns. the first two and last two column does not contains the header. So when i will use read.table then it will give an error line 2 did not have 44 elements. For solving this error i have used fill=TRUE. But using this it will resolve the error but the first two columns will be shifted in the columns with header A and R. Please provide some help on how to make read this kind of .txt files in r.

```
Last position-specific scoring matrix computed, weighted observed percentages rounded down, information per position, and relative weight of gapless real matches to pseudocounts


            A   R   N   D   C   Q   E   G   H   I   L   K   M   F   P   S   T   W   Y   V   A   R   N   D   C   Q   E   G   H   I   L   K   M   F   P   S   T   W   Y   V
    1 M    -1  -2  -2  -3  -2  -1  -2  -3  -2   1   2  -1   6   0  -3  -2  -1  -2  -1   1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.45 0.03
    2 K    -1   2   0  -1  -3   1   1  -2  -1  -3  -3   5  -1  -3  -1   0  -1  -3  -2  -2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.57 0.02
    3 K    -1   2   0  -1  -3   1   1  -2  -1  -3  -3   5  -1  -3  -1   0  -1  -3  -2  -2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.57 0.02
    4 R    -1   4   3   0  -2   0   0  -1   0  -3  -3   1  -2  -3  -2   2   0  -3  -2  -2    0  42  31   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  27   0   0   0   0  0.41 0.01
    5 I    -1  -2  -2  -2  -1  -2  -2  -3  -3   3   2  -2   1   0  -2  -1   2  -2  -1   1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  42  27   0   0   0   0   0  31   0   0   0  0.23 0.01
    6 L    -2  -3  -3  -3  -2  -3  -3  -4  -2   2   3  -3   1   3  -3  -2  -1  -1   1   1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  27  42   0   0  31   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.35 0.01
    7 S     0  -1   0  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1   1  -1  -1   0  -2  -1   3   1  -3  -2   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  31   0   0   0   0   0  69   0   0   0   0  0.23 0.01
    8 A     4  -1  -2  -2   0  -1  -1   0  -2  -1  -2  -1  -1  -2  -1   1   0  -3  -2   0  100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.44 0.02
    9 V    -1  -3  -3  -3  -1  -2  -3  -3  -3   3   1  -2   1  -1  -3  -2   0  -3  -1   4    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  31   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  69  0.37 0.01
```

Comment: If this is just a one-time occurrence then add the headers manually?

Answer (score 0):

It basically comes down to fiddling around with vectors that are then used to name the columns and rows. I can't think of another way to do it, if you do not want to change the file before reading it.

You didn't specify if the first two columns of your text file are separate variables or if they serve as row names. Therefore I arrive at a minimum of three different solutions. But the first three lines are the same for each solution:

```
# Reading the data without the header.
data <- read.table("data.txt", header = F, skip = 4)

# Reading only the header. Pay attention to the brackets at the end!
col.names <- read.table("data.txt", header = F, skip = 3, fill = T, stringsAsFactors = F)[1, ]
col.names <- as.character(col.names) # let's strip of the names for aesthetic reasons
```

From here on choose you desired outcome.

a) First two columns as separate variables:

```
a.col.names <- c("V1", "V2", col.names[1:42])

a.data <- data
names(a.data) <- a.col.names
```

b) First two columns as row names:

```
b.data <- data[3:NCOL(data)]

colnames(b.data) <- col.names[1:42]

b.row.names <- paste(data[[1]], data[[2]], sep = "")
rownames(b.data) <- b.row.names
```

c) First column as row name, second column as separate variable:

```
c.data <- data[2:NCOL(data)]
c.col.names <- c("V1", col.names[1:42])
names(c.data) <- c.col.names
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. i am not getting exact answer which i want.

Comment: Could you make yourself a bit more specific?